# Using Hibernate reverse engineering creates mappingResources style but I need annotatedClasses

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

Using Hibernate reverse engineering creates mappingResources style but I need annotatedClasses.

Anyway to make "Hibernate reverse engineering" to make the code annotatedClasses style and not mappingResources style?

I am trying to take a large mySQL database and make java classes with annotated in them.

Please let me know if anyone has done this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that with [Hibernate Tools](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html), an `Eclipse` plugin.

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools/). Every steps are explains. When you are generating the `.java` files, you can choose between `xml` file and `JPA` annotations.

To generate annotations, check `Generate EJB3 annotations` and `Use Java 5 syntax`

[image]

Comment: I dont see how it will make "annotatedClasses style". I been trying it and only see "mappingResources" style

Comment: but I am not using EJBs.. I am using mySQL

Comment: EJB has nothing to do with the database provider... It only means that it will use JPA annotations to annotate your classes... it works for any database (mySQL, Oracle, Etc.)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add the annotations support to the dependencies of your project. It depends on the version of hibernate do you use. As for the hibernate 4 annotations already included in the core jar, however make sure hibernate-commons-annotations included also. Then the reverse engineering wizard will let you choose how do you want to map the generated classes.